# Hibernate criteria for difference between 2 columns

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I have a trivial hibernate entity with 2 fields - `a` and `b`:

```
@Entity
public class PlayerEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer a;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer b;
}
```

I need to select all the players where `a - b > 5`.
Can this be ever done using standard Hibernate Criteria API? Can I somehow **avoid using SQL/HQL** for this rather typical condition?
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Restrictions.sqlRestriction()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#sqlRestriction%28java.lang.String%29) to produce a `Criterion` using a SQL condition:

```
List<PlayerEntity> playerList = (List<PlayerEntity>)session.createCriteria(PlayerEntity.class)
.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("(a- b) > 5")).list();
```

which will generate the SQL : `select * from PlayerEntity  where (a-b) > 5`

If you don't want to use the SQL to specify condition in the Criteria API ,you can define (a - b)  as the derived property using the  `@Formula` :

```
@Entity
public class PlayerEntity {

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private Integer a;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private Integer b;

  @Formula("a - b") 
  private Integer delta
}

List<PlayerEntity> playerList = (List<PlayerEntity>)session.createCriteria(PlayerEntity.class)
.add(Restrictions.gt("delta", 5).list();
```

Please note that the value of @Formula is the actual column name instead of the mapped property names.

Comment: Thanks Ken. But as I mentioned in a question, I'm trying to avoid using SQL/HQL.